# XAMARIN 6.3 MacOS Mono Update: F# interactive (and more) crashing

Tags: macos, xamarin, f#, mono, deedle

a message prompted this morning in Xamarin to update Mono SDK (to 5.0.0 ?), and i naively accepted it

1) I'm getting errors with scripts who can't properly load libraries anymore. (for example Fslab.fsx to load Deedle etc...)

2) in FSI, i'm getting randomly at times the message

> non-IL or abstract method with non-zero RVA

3) a simple type definition such like

```
type Dollar = Dollar of float
```

is returning me

> System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier
>   error  Specified method is not supported. at 1,0

I don't want to find other bugs, i'm sure the list is not exhaustive. I'm just pissed off, because i can't work anymore and i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed quite a few bugs due to Xamarin
so i have upgraded to VS Mac (latest with Mono 5.0.1), Xamarin is deprecated.

The bugs above are resolved, however I'm still experiencing many problems
like those described in this thread

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56097

Answer (score 2):

This bug is due to a combination of Xamarin Studio 6.3 being used with Mono 5.0

Either use Visual Studio for Mac with Mono 5.0+ or Xamarin Studio with Mono 4.8